# .Net Enumerable extension that executes an Action and returns the same enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

Is there a way to use the `IEnumerable` extension [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), (or any other `IEnumerable` extension)
to perform the equivalent of a `ForEach()` that returns the enumeration?  i.e., Can you already do, with a built-in provided `IEnumerable` extension, what would be the equivalent of this custom extension ?

```
  public static class EnumerableExtensions
  {
      public static IEnumerable<T> Do<T>
          (this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
      {
         foreach (var elem in source)
         {
            action(elem);
            yield return elem;
         }
     }
 }
```

For those comments below,  this method is not exactly the same as calling foreach.  In the case of foreach, the enumeration is not returned.  In this case, the purpose of the construction is simply to perform the action, so it can hardly be called a side-effect.

It allows chaining of Actions, as in

```
var Invoices = GetUnProcessedInvoices();
Invoices.Where(i=>i.Date > someDate)
      .Do(i=>SendEmail(i.Customer))
      .Do(i=>ShipProduct(i.Customer, i.Product, i.Quamtity))
      .Do(i=>Inventory.Adjust(i.Product, i.Quantity));
```

Comment: Probably not, as `action(elem);` reeks of side-effects.

Comment: Indeed; if anything, it would be a `Func<T,T>()` rather than an `Action`; and then you would just use it with `Select()`.

Comment: [The LINQ designers actively chose not to include such a method.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)  It's simply contrary to the entire design of `LINQ`.  Just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like jquery where you can say: elements.DoStuff().ThenOtherStuff().Foo().Bar()?

Comment: @Hank, I looked at Eric Lippert's blog about this, and his objections are about the ForEach variant, that does not return the enumeration.. What I am asking about performs the action AND returns the enumeration.  So it is, arguably, NOT a "side"-effect.  It is the PRIMARY, and ONLY effect.  It allows to chain actions on an enumeration.  I am curious, does this distinction matter to you?

Comment: @CharlesBretana No it does not.  Such a method is still *only* useful for its side effects.  If the action performs no side effects then the method still doesn't do anything at all.  Because it is only useful for its side effects, all of the exact same arguments apply.  Well, I suppose to be technical you're transforming whatever the sequence is into an `IEnumerable`, so it has all of the same uses as `AsEnumerable`, but you're clearly not intending to use it for those reasons, and `AsEnumerable` already exists anyway.

Comment: @Servy,  not being argumentative, but wht would you call it a "Side-effect" if that it is only, *intended* effect?

Comment: All of the things that you're not calling side effects in your edit are all side effects.

Comment: If you did this, `items.Do(action).Where(filter)` and `items.Where(filter).Do(action)` would not be equivalent. Don't you think that's counter-intuitive?

Comment: @CharlesBretana The term "side effect" has a different meaning in the context of programming.  A side effect is when an expression mutates some form of state, instead of the expression returning a value and never causing any changes to state.

Comment: The proper way to write a query such as in your edit would be to have a `foreach` loop and do everything you're doing in your `Do` loop in the body of the `foreach`.

Comment: @McLean, No not all, just as I would not consider `foo();  bar();` to be equivalent to `bar();  foo();`  They are in a different order.  I am curious, Why would anyone consider them equivalent?

Comment: @CharlesBretana But the expectations of LINQ are different since there are normally no side-effects within a query. If you replace `Do(action)` with `Select(x => x)`, they *are* equivalent. Similarly, multiple consecutive `Where` filters can be applied in any order with the same result.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, you never answered my question, but the reason why I ask is because if you DID want to do method chaining, then I think a better approach may be to have enumerable extension methods that specifically target  IEnumerable<TheTypeYouCareAbout> rather than a generic *Do* method. Then your code becomes very simple to read: E.g,. elements.SomeMethodWithASideEffect().SomeOtherMethodsThatSetsAProperty("foo"). Etc.

Comment: @Servy, I agree that your suggestion about using `foreach` loop is equivalent.   I know it can be done using the custom extension in my question. I am simply asking if there is a way to do this using linq.  This approach is no less proper than any other "equivalent" approach, and is just an attempt to represent the logical algorithm in a more "functional" style.

Comment: @CharlesBretana And I'm telling you that the LINQ designers *specifically* didn't include such a method very intentionally because it's considered contrary to the design of LINQ.  It's very much *not* a functional style of programming.  In a purely functional language *generating side effects is **impossible***.  Anything that causes side effects is very explicitly *not* functional.  The functional approach to programming would be to re-design the program to not need to rely on side effects at all.

Comment: @Servy,  I give up. WHY is it a "Side Effect" ??  What is your definition of "side-effect" ??  Just using a pejorative buzz-word is not an argument.  If the only "effect" I intend, and code for, is a "side-effect" in your view, then your comments are useless.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I already explained to you what a side effect is.  It is not my definition, it is a widely used, and well defined, term within the field of computer science.  See [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) if you want a more detailed definition.  It is a technical term, one that is not subjective.  It is an *objective fact* that the statements you are performing are side effects, not a subjective opinion.  That is it your primary intent to cause side effects *is what makes this not a functional design* and why it conflicts with LINQ.

Comment: @Servy,  After looking through the other members of the Enumerable extension methods, I notice that none of them modify the individual members of the enumeration.  If that's what you are talking about, I think I understand your point now... Your use of the term "side-effect" was confusing. To me, a side-effect is something *other* than what was intended.  If I get it, you saying that what I want is contrary to this general pattern - that LINQ designers do not want any extension method to have ANY effect on the members of the enumeration.  ...

Comment: @CharlesBretana It goes beyond that.  Mutating the items in the sequence is one type of side effect.  Another is sending an email, shipping a product, or adjusting an inventory.  Any mutations of the state of the program is a side effect.  The only operation without side effects is where there are no possible observable effect that it has run, other than looking at what it returns.  `1+1` has no side effects.  Other than using the result `2`, you wouldn't be able to tell that it has run.  You could put it anywhere in the program and it wouldn't change it, if you don't observe the result.

Comment: @Servy,  in the wiki article, it makes the point that an effect can be considered a side-effect if the function cannot simply be replaced in the code with the literal value returned by the function, with no change in program behavior.  This example made the light bulb come on for me very effectively. Any function *without* a return value (with `void` return in .Net) would by necessity fall into this category (or it would be pointless). So, I understand this now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has released the NuGet package [Ix-Main](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main/) which includes various useful extensions like `Do()`.

Your example:

```
var Invoices = GetUnProcessedInvoices();
Invoices.Where(i=>i.Date > someDate)
      .Do(i=>SendEmail(i.Customer))
      .Do(i=>ShipProduct(i.Customer, i.Product, i.Quamtity))
      .Do(i=>Inventory.Adjust(i.Product, i.Quantity));
```

Will work out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
var result = source.Select(x => { action(x); return x; });
```

But of course lazy evalution means it won't get executed until you evaluate the result:

```
var result = source.Select(x => { action(x); return x; });
var list = result.ToList(); // action executed here for each element
```

And if the enumeration is not fully enumerated, action won't be called for all elements:

```
var result = source.Select(x => { action(x); return x; });
var first = result.First(); // action executed here only for first element
```

And if the user enumerates multiple times, your action will be enumerated multiple times, as in the following contrived example:

```
var result = source.Select(x => { action(x); return x; });
if (result.Count() > 0) // Count() enumerates and calls action() for each element
{
    return result.ToList(); // ToList() enumerates and calls action() again for each element.
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

IMHO it's probably confusing to rely on the user of your enumeration to ensure your action is called exactly once, so I would generally avoid this design.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your method is just to use Select:

```
var x = list.Select(x => { x.Something(); return x; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a side effect in several LINQ extension methods, like `Where` and `Select`:

```
var en = enumeration.Where(x => { action(x); return true; });
```

or:

```
var en = enumeration.Select(x => { action(x); return x; });
```

You get the shortest code if your action returns the value that it is called with, then you can use the method as delegate in the extension method:

```
var en = enumeration.Select(action);
```

or if it always returns `true`:

```
var en = enumeration.Where(action);
```

To have the method actually called, you also have to use something that will actually enumerate the collection, like the `Last()` method:

```
en.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll add my comment as an answer. I think if you want a code base to use chaining, then the code base should really support it. Otherwise, each developer may or may not write in the functional style that you want. So, I would do this:

```
  public static class EnumerableExtensions {

    public static IEnumerable<Invoice> SendEmail(this IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices) {
        foreach (var invoice in invoices) {
            SendEmail(invoice.Customer);
            yield return invoice;
        }
    }        

    public static IEnumerable<Invoice> ShipProduct(this IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices) {
        foreach (var invoice in invoices) {
            ShipProduct(invoice.Customer, invoice.Product, invoice.Quantity);
            yield return invoice;
        }
    }                     

    public static IEnumerable<Invoice> AdjustInventory(this IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices) {
        foreach (var invoice in invoices) {
            AdjustInventory(invoice.Product, invoice.Quantity);
            yield return invoice;
        }
    }


    private static void SendEmail(object p) {
        Console.WriteLine("Email!");
    }
    private static void AdjustInventory(object p1, object p2) {
        Console.WriteLine("Adjust inventory!");
    }
    private static void ShipProduct(object p1, object p2, object p3) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ship!");
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
invoices.SendEmail().ShipProduct().AdjustInventory().ToList();
```

Of course, I'm not sure about the ToList() part. If you forget to call that then nothing happens :). I was just copying your current extension methods, but it might make more sense to not use yield so that you could just do:

```
invoices.SendEmail().ShipProduct().AdjustInventory();
```

Comment: I like this... the syntax for its use is terse and yet clear.    It does not, however, allow for arbitrary generic actions, with side effects, to be executed on each element in an enumeration... you have to create an extension method for each new action you want to execute (that you don't already have an extension for...)

Comment: Absolutely. As I said, this is if you really want to embrace method chaining, and not do it as a sort of one off sort of thing. I would expect that you would have other classes that are doing the heavy lifting, so the extension method just calls though. So, to add a new extension method wouldn't be a big deal, and presumably you aren't going to be doing that everyday anyway. You're going to call the methods a lot more often than you're going to write the method :). And, as you said, it's more terse. I'd rather write that kind of code then then all the `.Do()`s. My two cents.